# How to check the css file is loaded on not in the current page using javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, css, master-page, html

I need to check the preticular css file is loaded or not in the current page using javascript.

Suggest any idea to find this using javascript.

Answer (score 2):

## 1. CSS says: Hello I was (not) loaded

If you have control over how the CSS is loaded you can add events

This extract from my Fabric Iconator checks if the file was **not** loaded

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
      id="FabricCore601"
      onerror="disableMissingFabricCore(this);"
      href="//spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/6.0.1/css/fabric.min.css">
</link>
```

So you can add the `onload` (for a succesful load) event and track whatever you need to track

## 2. Hello CSS, are you a DOM element?

`LINK` and `STYLE` tags are DOM elements, so like any element you can check if they exist

```
var myCSS=document.querySelector("link[href*='6.0.1']")
```

will return `undefined` if it doesn't exist